# Why is setting SynchronousUpdating -> True causes mouse motion to pause/freeze Dynamics?

Tags: dynamic

When making a Manipulate, I noticed that setting `SynchronousUpdating -> True` have a very annoying side effect. By just moving the mouse anywhere on the same cell the Manipulate is running, causes pauses and short freezes in the display of the Manipulate.

Even if one is not pressing on anything. Simply touching the mouse and just making small move in the cell, even if not on top of the Manipulate display, it will cause short pauses in the Manipulate display.

Here is a MWE. It is 3D graphics. It runs for ever rotating very smoothly until the mouse in touched and moved on the cell

[image]

Will now do the same thing, but make `SynchronousUpdating -> False`. Now there are no pauses and no freezes in the display

[image]

This only shows up in Version 10. I tested this on version 9 and this problem do not show up there. This is on windows 7, running version 10.1.

Could someone explain why setting `SynchronousUpdating -> True` have this side effect? Is this a bug? Is this supposed to be like this?

ps. there was discussion on this at chat. This problem seems to show up on windows only and not on the mac with version 10.1

Here is the code for the above:

```
Manipulate[
 tick = Not[tick];
 Module[{},
  x = Mod[x + 1, 360];
  Graphics3D[
   Rotate[
    {
     Cylinder[{{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}],
     Rotate[Cylinder[{{-2, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}, 1/2], 
      x/2 Degree, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}],
     Rotate[Cylinder[{{-2, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}, 1/2], 
      x/3 Degree, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}]
     }, x Degree, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}],
   PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}
   ]
  ],
 {{tick, False}, None},
 {{x, 0}, None},
 SynchronousUpdating -> True,
 TrackedSymbols :> {tick}
 ]
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this freeze in 10.1. (My OS is Windows 8.1 64bit.) Could it be issues related to graphics card and/or mouse drivers?

Comment: @Silvia thanks for testing. This might be windows 7 specific issue then? Do not know.

Comment: I was able to reproduce it on 10.1 with Win7-64bit. I see the same small freezes at the *very beginning* of each mouse movement.

Comment: I am on a Macbook Pro 15 late 2013 model with nvidia 750m graphics running MacOS 10.10.3 and Mathematica 10.1 and I do get some stuttering when moving the mouse cursor. It is not as extreme as shown above, but the whole animation slows down quite considerably when doing nonstop movement with the mouse cursor.

Comment: @Wizard thanks for testing. The short pauses/short freezes  can become more extreme as more things are being played out. The above is a small example. In my other demo, which is larger than this ofcourse, the freezing was very bad and longer each time the mouse is moved.